# How to extend Node<T extends Comparable<T>> class

Tags: java, generics, extends

I have an abstract class that is like this:

```
public abstract class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

I need `extends Comparable<T>` so that I may use `.compareTo()` with generic type `T`.

I try to extend this class with this sub-class declaration:

```
public class ListNode<T> extends Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

However this throws SyntaxErrors in eclipse for the second `extends` and for the final two `>>`.

Is this the way to declare the sub-class? It seems so messy.

```
public class ListNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

How should this be done? Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Node` as

```
public abstract class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>{}
```

`ListNode` can be:

```
public class ListNode<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Node<T>
```

The key thing to note is that the type parameter after the name of the declared class is what constrains T for everything else in the class. This includes the other types extended by the declared class.

This means that once you have bounded `T` you don't need to do it again in the `extends`/`implements` statements.